# Javascript i can't add a new paragraph using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hi im having this problem, when i use the code only for the

(without the "demo2" ) works fine, and in the browser i can see the text that its on "PruebasGeneral/MBVR000008.txt" and when i change this file/text, works in my HTML  without refreshing, but i need to add another

as you can see, i tried to add in the same  function, but doesnt work, with this code in the browser in the two paragraph shows whats inside "PruebasGeneral/MBVR000009.txt" so basically shows demo2 and demo2. WHAT SHOULD I DO?

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>


<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>


<script>


function loadDoc(path, callback) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      callback(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", path + "?t=" + Math.random(), true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function data1Loaded(data) {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data ; // do something with data
}

function data2Loaded(data) {
 document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = data ; // do something with data
}

function loadDocs() {
  loadDoc('/PruebasGeneral/MBVR000008.txt', data1Loaded);
  loadDoc('/PruebasGeneral/MBVR000009.txt', data2Loaded);

  setTimeout(loadDocs, 1000);
}

window.onload = loadDocs;
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please edit in a more useful title that isn't in all caps? Louder words only annoy

Comment: i did it, sorry if the tittle annoys you. im new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have all of that over again. You can't just call `open()` twice:

```js
function loadDoc(path, callback) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      callback(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", path + "?t=" + Math.random(), true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function data1Loaded(data) {
  // do something with data
}

function data2Loaded(data) {
  // do something with data
}

function loadDocs() {
  loadDoc('path1', data1Loaded);
  loadDoc('path2', data2Loaded);
  
  setTimeout(loadDocs, 1000);
}

window.onload = loadDocs;
```

Comment: sorry for saying this, but im kinda newbie on here, how can i use your code using "demo" and "demo2" as the paragraph's ID and, also the xhttp.open("GET", path + "?t=" + Math.random(),  true); that in my case is "/PruebasGeneral/MBVR000001.txt?t=" ... please if you dont mind. and it works if i wanna more?

Comment: Change `path1` and `path2` to those strings that you have. Then in `data1Loaded` and `data2Loaded`, the `data` variable will be the result so you would put just move your `document.getElementById()` code into the appropriate functions.

Comment: Im having an error here: xhttp.open("GET", path + "?t=" + Math.random(), true);  in the browser shows the two data "undefined" and "Request URL:http://localhost/PruebasGeneral/[object%20Event]?t=0.4763424311685205"  error in object

Comment: Can you add to your question and include your updated code? Do a big line of hyphens (------) and then put the updates below that so your original question is still there too.

Comment: yeah, i just did it mate.

Comment: Your problem appears to be you are doing `this.responseText` in the `data1Loaded()` and `data2Loaded()` you are using ` = this.responseText;`. It should be `= data;` instead.

Comment: Yeahhhh thanks so much my friend, its working now !  i would like to ask you something, you are using the window.onload, if i want to use window.addEventListener  changes a lot?

Comment: Nope. In fact, your way is generally better practice. I just couldn't remember which you used when I was writing my code. ;)

Comment: haha, so what should i change  for using window.addEventListener , 'cause actually my boss is telling to use this one ...  if you dont mind mate.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', loadDocs)`. Pretty much what you had before.

Comment: Thanks mate.! you are VIP!